# Can't override option version in setup.py despite pyproject.toml

Tags: python, version, setuptools, setup.py, pyproject.toml

What I am trying to achieve is to create a GitHub workflow that releases my Python library to PyPI when someone pushed on one of the tags (i.e., 1.0.0, 1.1.0) and set it to be the `version` of the release.

Howevery, I am having trouble to override the project version in `setup.py` file despite `pyproject.toml` file is taking over the option version.

I have tried setting the keyword `version` in the `setup.py` file, but it still uses `pyproject.toml`'s version keyword:

```ini
[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
version = {attr = "myproject.__version__"}
```

```py
setup(
    ...
    version=os.getenv("PROJECT_VERSION"),  # This does not overrides pyproject
    ...
)
```

I have tested it thoroughly, but it still sets the version option from the `pyproject.toml` file.